# Jquery: How to apply window.location.hash as same number as in button id automatically?

Tags: jquery, hash, automation, window.location

I have a webpage with at least 300 buttons.

This is a stripped down version of my buttons for this question.

```
$(".button2").click( function() {
ajaxFunction(gallery[2]);    
});

$(".button3").click( function() {
ajaxFunction(gallery[3]);

});
```

etc, etc

I need to figure out a way that when lets say #button2 is clicked, it would automatically apply:  window.location.hash = '#gallery2'. If #button3 is clicked it would add window.location.hash = '#gallery3', etc, etc.

There are several hundred buttons so I'm trying to avoid manual input here lol.

Is there a way to grab the number at the end of the '#button[number]' and add it to window.location.hash = '#gallery[that number]'

Hopefully, I have explained this clearly.

Thanks

Comment: A simple regex pattern like `/\d+/` might work? Something like: `this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex pattern like /\d+/ could work.

Something like:

```
$(".button2").click( function() {
    ajaxFunction('#gallery' + this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]);    
});
```

Edit: From your comments, it appears you have the answer. You just need to apply that to ALL buttons without adding hundreds of click handlers :)

For that, you'll need to look into `event delegation`. jQuery provides this easily through their `on` method. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="button1">...</button>
    <button class="button2">...</button>
    <button class="button3">...</button>
    <button class="button4">...</button>
    <button class="button5">...</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('.container').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var $btn = $(this);
        var className = $btn.attr('class'); // or Id
        var idNum = className.match(/\d+/)[0];
        ajaxFunction('#gallery' + idNum);
    });
</script>
```

Something like that would allow you to have a single `click` handler that would listen to all clicks that `bubble` up from its children. Sometimes people do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.selector', handler);
```

Generally though, you'll want the handler bound as close to your buttons as possible.

One major advantage to event delegation is that if you have 1000 buttons that all need to respond, you're only binding one listener, as opposed to a thousand listeners for each button. It's also just one line of script that needs modifying, rather than 1000 lines of code :)

Hope that helps!

jQuery's [on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Hi Jack, I actually adjusted it similarly, 
`$(".button2").click( function() {
var idnum = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/);
window.location.hash = ('#gallery' + idnum);
}`
But that would require manual input to every button.  Is there a way to apply it to every button that has a number in it's classname?

Comment: There is, @DC1 - You're looking for `event delegation`. I'll adjust my answer appropriately!

Comment: Hi Jack,

Because I didn't use the actual 'button' tag (I used divs classed as .button1, etc), I had to set it for clicks on any div in '.container'
This is the final working code, thanks to your approach!

`$(".container").on('click', 'div', function() { 
var idnum = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/); 
window.location.hash = ('#gallery' + idnum); 
});`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It means modifying your HTML, but I'd recommend using data attributes:

```
<input class="myGalleryBtn" value="Clicky" type="button" data-id="3" />
```

And when the button is clicked you pick up this attribute:

```
$(".myGalleryBtn").click(function(){
    var galleryid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    window.location.hash = "#gallery" + galleryid;
});
```

You could start counting characters and splitting strings on 'button', but it's a bit hacky and this method is a common approach to storing and picking up arbitrary values from the DOM.

https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Answer (score 1):

If you could add a data attribute on each of the buttons to indicate the gallery, that would make things nice and clean. If you *can't* do it, you can still get there, but it's going to be a little messy.

```
$('<button-selector>').click(function() {
  var buttonClasses = this.classList.value;
  var galleryNumber = buttonClasses.match(/button(\d+)/)[1];
  window.location.hash = '#gallery' + galleryNumber;
});
```

where `<button-selector>` is some selector that will select all your buttons.

A quick explanation of the regular expression I'm using here. `.match()` is a string method that runs a regular expression against a string and returns an array of information about the match. The argument I'm passing to it is the regular expression (surrounded by the forward slashes).

This regular expression first matches a literal string `button`. It will then **capture** a match (denoted by the parentheses) for **one or more** (denoted by `+`) **numeric digits** (denoted by `\d`). The second array element returned from `match` is the captured portion of the match. In this case, that second argument will be the numeric digits following `button` in the `classList`.

If you could add a data attribute instead, (like `<button data-gallery="76">Gallery 76</button>`), you could do this:

```
$('<button-selector>').click(function() {
  var galleryNumber = this.dataset.gallery;
  window.location.hash = '#gallery' + galleryNumber;
});
```